# Yii2 property mapping to tablename

Tags: yii2, php-7, yii2-basic-app

I use Yii2 2.0.9 basic template and I try to set up my class.
I my class I use references of other classes in my property.

```
/**
*
*@property Contact contact
*/
class User extends ActiveRecord {

    public static function tableName() {
        return "user";
    }

    /**
    * This is want I need
    */
    public function databaseMapping(){
        return [
            "contact" => "contact_id"
        ];
    }
}
```

Is there in Yii2 a solution for my problem?

Thanks Marvin Thör

In Grails I can write this:

```
class User {

    Contact contact
    Boolean passwordExpired

    static mapping = {

        contact(column: 'contact_id')
        passwordExpired(column: 'password_expired')
    }    
}

User user = new User();
user.passwordExpired = true
user.contact = new Contact();
```

and I want the same

Comment: Can you describe your problem little more? Are you want to change attribute name and db column name different?

Comment: I need a other name in the database for my properties. In my class my I have contact but I need it as contact_id in the database

Comment: Why you want to change column name different?  change your label name. That would be easy.

Comment: @SRana I need it the reason is my problem

Comment: then why don't you keep the same name in your class as the database attribute name? why do you need the attribute in your class to be `contact`?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the method `attributeLabels()` inside your model class to define label names to show to the end user.

```
public function attributeLabels() {
    return [
        'contact_id' => 'Contact',
    ];
}
```

However, there are times like when creating a RESTful API using Yii2 that you need to return a json with fields with specific field names. For these ocasions, you can use the `fields()` method:

```
public function fields() {
    return [
        'contact' => 'contact_id',
    ];
}
```

This method returns the list of fields that should be returned by default by `toArray()`. You can check more about it [HERE](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#fields()-detail).

Answer (score 0):

Change your labels and db column remain unchanged.

```
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'contact_id' => Yii::t('app', 'Use your name here'),

    ];
}
```